# What is the reward for DK-Mario-Hat in the slots minigame?

Tags: donkey-kong-94

The slots minigame shows the reward for DK-Mario-Hat as ?-up. What does this mean? Does something special happen if you get DK-Mario-Hat in the slots minigame?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Mariowiki, the amount of lives you get when making that combination is a random amount.

Source: https://www.mariowiki.com/Donkey_Kong_(Game_Boy)